# Store len() of a list from loop in variable

Tags: python, list, loops, variables

I create a list `D1` inside a loop ten times.

At this time `D1` always contains 731 values.
So I have `10 x D1` with 731 values.
Then I filter `D1` for all values `< -50` and `> +50`.
Now I have 10 different lists `b50`, and want to save the length of `b50` in a list `len_b50`. 
So at the end `len_b50` should contain 10 values depicting the length of `b50`, for example like:

```
len_b50 = [643,510,451,391,274,197,128,76,55,31]
```

See the following code sample what I tried:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    D1=x.tolist()

    b50=[]
    len_b50=[]
    for t in range(0,731):
        if(D1[t]>50 or D1[t]<-50):
             b50.append(D1[t])

    len_b50.append(len(b50))
    print(len_b50)
```

All I accomplished was a list containing just the current length value of `b50`, which was overwrited every time.
Can somebody help me with this? I have no idea how to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: initialize your len_b50 empty list outside of your loop and each time you finish your first for loop append to the len_b50 list the result of len(b50).

Comment: You should have shown us what you actually tried to do with the `len_b50` there. That way, we could have told you exactly what you were doing wrong. But now, you’re just going to get a finished solution instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I edited it again, maybe now it is better!

Comment: You clear your list in every iteration `len_b50 = []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign an empty list `[]` to `len_b50` on each loop iteration, i.e., you clear it before each time you start accumulating into `b50`.

You want to initialize `len_b50` to `[]` *outside* the loop. That way the list object persists between loop iterations.

Comment: Thanks you are right! I thought I tried this already but apparently I didn't :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the main issue is that you're not appending the list `D1` to `b50`, but rather you're appending a single element from `D1` to `b50`.  Also, you're not creating a new `D1` in each of the 10 iterations, so you shouldn't expect to see different lengths for each of the 10 lists, post-thresholding.

If you want `b50` to be a list of 10 lists, and if you want those lists to be filtered versions of `D1`, based on the threshold check you provided, then this solution might help clear things up:

First, generate some sample data, making a new random list on each loop.
Then, filter out the elements in each list that don't meet the threshold criteria.
Finally, store the filtered lists in `b50`, and store a list of their lengths in `len_b50`.

```
import numpy as np

# number of elements in array
N = 731 
# number of lists to make
n_iter = 10
# threshold value
thresh = 50

b50 = []

for i in range(n_iter):
    x = np.random.randint(-100,100, size=N)
    D1 = [value for value in x if abs(value) > abs(thresh)]
    b50.append(D1)

len(b50)
10
```

Now find the lengths of each list in `b50`:

```
len_b50 = [len(x) for x in b50]
print(len_b50)
[390, 366, 363, 345, 346, 375, 350, 358, 359, 366]
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `len_b50` out of the for loop
Also just have `t` loop over the items in `D1`

```
len_b50 = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    D1 = x.tolist()

    b50 = []
    for t in D1:
        if (t > 50 or t < -50):
             b50.append(t)

    len_b50.append(len(b50))

print(len_b50)
```

Now you could use a list comprehension

```
len_b50 = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    D1 = x.tolist()

    b50 = [t for t in D1 if (t > 50 or t < -50)]
    len_b50.append(len(b50))

print(len_b50)
```